# The parametric representation of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, parametric

I have a lecture for my linear algebra and geometry module that focuses on the cross product and line and planes within Euclidean geometry. The lecture notes talk about the parametric representation of a line which is something I covered in my A-levels, however I can't make the connection in my head between what I learned at A-level and what was in the lecture leading to me not being able to understand this content. The part that I am struggling on is as follows:

The straight line through the point $P\in\Bbb R^n$ in direction of vector $\vec a$ has the parametric form:
$$\vec x (t)=P+\vec a t\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R$$
Similarly, given two points $P, Q\in\Bbb R^n$, the line passing through $P$ and $Q$ has parametric form:
$$\vec x (t)=P+t(Q-P)\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R$$
I was wondering if anyone could explain how this links back to earlier content that I have studied, hopefully allowing me to understand this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Your question lacks focus (what exactly is unclear to you) and doesn't show any effort of your own. Furthermore, you should include the relevant text in your question, formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of a link to a picture. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3959921/edit) your question accordingly. For now, it is likely to get closed.

Comment: What exactly was the representation you learned previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\vec{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
A good place to start would be a visual example. Suppose $\vect a = (1,2)$ and $\vect y_0= (-1,0)$. We want the line through $\vect y_0$ in the direction of $\vect a$. This is given by

$$\left\{ \vect x \in \Bbb R^2 \; \middle| \; \vect x = t \vect a + \vect y_0 \text{ for some } t \in \Bbb R \right\}$$

Here is what we get if we visualize the elements of this set for $t \in \{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$:

[image]

What do we notice? This appears to be a line with slope $2$, and $y$-intercept $2$ as well. That means the equation of the line -- once we span over all of $t \in \R$ -- is given by

$$y = 2x+2$$

That's interesting, because $2 = a_y/a_x = 2/1$ (where $a_x$ denotes the $n$ component of $\vect a$, and similar for $y$). $y$ in particular goes through $\vect y_0$. So let's consider $\vect a$ as representing a slope through the ratio of its points, and $\vect y_0$ as a single point through which the line goes. This uniquely determines the line via its point slope form: the equation of a line with slope $m$ going through $(x',y')$ is given by

$$y - y' = m(x-x')$$

Given a vector $\vect a$ and $\vect y_0$, then

$$y - y_{0,y} = \frac{a_y}{a_x} (x - y_{0,x})$$

Plugging in $y_{0,x} = -1$, $y_{0,y} = 0$, $a_y = 2$, and $a_x = 1$, we have

$$y - 0 = \frac{2}{1} (x - (-1)) \implies y = 2x+2$$

---

We can work this similarly for your "line through two points" thing. Suppose we have, now, $\vect a = (1,3)$ and $\vect b = (2,1)$. The line in the green is the unique line through these two points:

[image]

Notice however, we can get a third vector from this (up to its orientation): the vector $\vect c = \vect b - \vect a$ (or the vector $\vect d = \vect a - \vect b$). Choosing $\vect c$ because why not, we then have this picture:

[image]

Notice, however, the line that we want is precisely the set of all vectors that are scalar multiples of $\vect c$ from that position. That is, we have the line is given by

$$\left\{ \vect x \in \Bbb R^2 \; \middle| \; \vect x = t \vect c + \vect a \text{ for some } t \in \Bbb R \right\}$$

**Some Notes:** You can use $\vect d$ in lieu of $\vect c$, and $\vect a$ in lieu of $\vect b$ in the above definition. We just want a line through $\vect a$ and $\vect b$, and $\vect c$ or $\vect d$ go in the direction necessary. Carefully examine how this is similar to our previous example! The choice of $\vect c$ versus $\vect d$, or $\vect a$ versus $\vect b$, is superfluous for this application and the end result is ultimately the same even if the definition looks different. If we were to limit $t$ to $0 \le t \le 1$, as we do when parameterizing a **line segment** specifically, it would be a different matter.

Anyhow, since $\vect c = \vect b - \vect a$, then we have that the set is equivalent to

$$\left\{ \vect x \in \Bbb R^2 \; \middle| \; \vect x = \vect a + t \left(\vect b - \vect a \right) \text{ for some } t \in \Bbb R \right\}$$

You can then re-analyze this through our opening example and explanation -- a line with given slope through a point, since $\vect b - \vect a$ (the thing $t$ scales) determines the slope of the line, and $\vect a$ determines the location through which the line goes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 3D vectors online to understand how your teacher maps this onto a graph it will help a lot with your understanding